# Is this code wrong? Im getting an invalid syntax error. Im a beginner coder in high school btw

Tags: python-2.x

I'm coding a program that based on your mood, it will give you quotes. Sort of like a motivational quote app. It isn't finished yet and I'm aware the lists aren't programmed yet.

```py
import random

UserFeeling_str = raw_input("How are you feeling today?")
 if UserFeeling_str == "upset

 if UserFeeling_str == "sad":

 if UserFeeling_str == "bad":

  if UserFeeling_str == "not great":

      print(random.choice(upset.list))  


if UserFeeling_str == "happy":

 if UserFeeling_str == "good":

 if UserFeeling_str == "okay":

 if UserFeeling_str == "ok":

 print(random.choice(motiv.list))
```

and when I run the code:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/ex50/app.py", line 9
UserFeeling_str = raw_input("How are you feeling today?")
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Process exited with code: 0
```

Comment: First, get an IDE or editor that does syntax highlighting, like stackoverflow does when you format your code as code. It's not fairly easy to spot where something's off. When you run into other errors that are not caught by syntax highlighting, look not only at the line where the error is reported, but at one or two lines above that. Often this is where the real error is, but the compiler only noticed it a bit later.

Comment: You're missing a close quote and your indentation is erratic.

Answer (score 2):

Notice the type of error that it is giving you is a "syntax error" those are types of errors where usually there is something that is missing or added in terms of a character or two that is misplaced, ie, the syntax is bad for the interpreter.

Just from what I see:

if UserFeeling_str == "upset

needs to be

if UserFeeling_str == "upset":

notice the quotation mark and colon.

Comment: yeah i noticed that. it was an accident bc i backspaced too much. oops.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing  ": on your first if sentence.

Should be

`if UserFeeling_str == "upset":`

Also, don't forget the indent on every if block:

`If something:
        If something_else:
                #actions`